# How to implement Context Menu in PrimeNG Tree Select

Tags: angular, select, tree, contextmenu, primeng

I need to use a context menu with my treeselect. I've found examples with p-tree but when i try those example implementations with my p-treeselect component i get *"Can't bind to 'contextMenu' since it isn't a known property of 'p-treeSelect'"* error. My code is as below

```
<p-contextMenu #groupContextMenu [model]="groupContextMenuItems"></p-contextMenu>
<p-treeSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" [contextMenu]="groupContextMenu" selectionMode="single"
    [options]="groupNodes">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        <div class="flex">
            <p>{{node.data}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-treeSelect>
```

What should be done here to achieve desired result? Thanks in advance.